# Coffeescript + Angular Directive Syntax Error

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Im trying to write a directive in Angular in Coffeescript and am running into difficulties. Here is my directive code:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective3', () -> 
    #directive is used in ng-repeat

        return {

            scope: '@'
            restrict: 'E'
            template: 'My name is {{person.first}} {{person.last}}',
            link: (scope, element, attrs) -> 
                console.log("scope inside linking function")
                console.log(scope)


            }
        )
```

When I try to compile it, coffeescript is throwing an error:

```
error: unexpected :
            link : (scope,element,attributes) ->
                 ^^
```

I have looked several examples of how link is defined elsewhere and it seems precisely to use this : to denote key/value relationship in the dictionary to return. Is there something I'm missing here?

Commenting out the `link :` results in a working script

Thanks!

Comment: Is it because of the comma you placed at the end of template?

Comment: What is the use of the "->" at the end of that line? I'd assume it's a lambda syntax, like any other language, but does the basic link synatx work? Try link: function($scope, element, attrs) {console.log("scope inside linking function")
                console.log(scope)}

Comment: Also, are there suppose to be commas at the end of each property "scope: @,"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have tabs problems

```
myApp.directive('myDirective3', () ->
#directive is used in ng-repeat

    return {

        scope: '@'
        restrict: 'E'
        template: 'My name is {{person.first}} {{person.last}}',
        link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
            console.log("scope inside linking function")
            console.log(scope)


    }
)
```

should be compiled

Comment: Holy mackerel - you are right. it compiles! Thank you!